# New project from branch in SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn, branch, project, subversive

I'm using Eclipse with Subversive 4.0.5.

I have a SVN project with a lot of branches.

One of these branches needs to become a new SVN project:

```
Super_Project  
-> Great_Branch  
-> Good_Branch  
-> ...
```

In this example, Good_Branch should become the new SVN project Good_Project.

Is there a way to do this without losing the SVN history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out, that it's actually enough to create a new SVN project and copy the branch into the new projects branches.